# Use BatteryMeterView.java in android app

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the BatteryMeterView.java from AOSP into my own app to create a battery icon that responds to level change, charging state, etc.

I found this [source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/BatteryMeterView.java) on GitHub. Is it possible to integrate it into my app to create the icon and eventually the percent text?

I'm thinking about something like an `.xml` with

```
<com.example.app.BatteryMeterView
    android:id="@+id/battery_icon"
    android:layout_width="8dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
```

And `BatteryMeterView.java` file to be inside `com.example.app`

Also can I use the file in non open-source projects according its current Licence? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This should be be possible, you only need to include the all the resources and make a decision on whether or not you want to have `BatteryController` and ignore `DemoMode`. And make a decision of whether you want `hasOverlappingRendering()`.

### License Details

Read more @ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 , you're interested in the **redistribution** part.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do this but I checked the code and it includes many other java and resource files also.
You have to decide and analyze what are their roles and modify your code accordingly.